# how to instantiate and append to a QVector of pointers to my objects

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qvector

I need to instantiate and append to a QVector of pointers to my objects

My header says 
`QVector<Stuff*> myResults;`

By commenting stuff out I've narrowed it down to my use of the QVector

1) When I try to

```
    myResults.append(stuff);
```

2) and when I try to

```
    myResults.push_back(stuff);
```

I get

`First-chance exception at 0x00007FF652523520 in LibTestd.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000030.`

I've copied and pasted different ways to instantiate my qvector to no avail. Including the example from doc.qt.io with 0 and with 50 
`QVector<Stuff> vector(0);`

I've tried making the class type in the QVector not a pointer, and dereferenced stuff.

I don't really know whats going wrong but I'm fairly certain it's related to my misuse of pointers. Can someone give any ...pointers? :P

btw, in case it's relevant, the stuff translation unit *(by which i mean, the Stuff.h and Stuff.cpp files under the same name (is translation unit the name?))* has two classes in it, Crap class and Stuff class, Stuff can't exist without crap. I've got initialisation lists in my constructor that says so.

also btw, I instantiate stuff like this `Stuff * stuff = new Stuff()`

Comment: how is `myResults` defined exactly? `QVector<Stuff*> myResults;`?

Comment: Yea I tried that way
and also QVector<Stuff> myResults (and then dereferenced stuff when i tried that added it)

Comment: (Thanks for letting me know about the typo on the question, ill fix it up)
 I also tried QVector<Stuff> myResults; (and then dereferenced stuff when i tried that added it)
and QVector<Stuff> myResults(0); 
and QVector<Stuff> myResults(50);
and tried myResults = myResults(QVector<Stuff>(50)) (not in header)

Nothing is working which is why I think it's related to pointers, how it groups the memory and if its trying to copy the objects that are being pointed to or something.

Comment: what you have seems to be correct, are you sure that the vector is causing the exception?

Comment: super massive blonde moment >.> the class that creates the class that tries to use a Qvector...i aummm, forgot to instantiate..... *hides in shame over how long this confused me* but yay! new problems to be befuddled by!

Answer (score 0):

Without the rest of the code its hard to help, but.:

`QVector` does not deference the data its given, so check `myResults` variables validity at the time of execution.

Yes, I know its not a pointer but a class level variable, still, check it, especially if you are using `processEvents()` (or equivalent) on any thread that may run the destructor of your object.

If you find that the `myResults` variable is invalid (points to 0xfeeefeee + somewhat more in debug build, and/or is on "unable to read" memory, check if the destructor of the object run before the access violation.

It is common that ppl new or even rookie to Qt use `processEvents()` and does not reconsider that slots that lead to the destruction of their object may run during the processEvents() call.

Answer (score 0):

super massive blonde moment >.> 
The class that creates the class that tries to use a Qvector...i aummm, forgot to instantiate it..... 
* hides in shame over how long this confused me*
but yay! new problems to be befuddled by! still got other problems.